# What is someone who works with optical fibres and light called?

Tags: single-word-requests, science

I would like to know the name of a person who works with lasers and optical fibers? I have tried searching on google and asking people that I could get any answer from.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with English Language and Usage.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any specific term for someone who works with or studies optics.

Comment: We're probably going to need a description of the work, because often it's what one **does** which is described, rather than the materials. Please [edit the question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/411942/edit) to add that.

Comment: Depending on what they are doing with the lasers and fibers, they might be "optical engineers".

Comment: [Narinder Singh Kapany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narinder_Singh_Kapany) was a physicist.

Comment: Oh, oh, oh!!!   I really so much want to suggest "optician".  But I won't.

Answer (score 3):

The field is called "photonics". The person is a "photonics engineer", "photonics scientist", "photonics technician" etc. depending on what exactly they do.